# Isn't partial differentiation implied by function context?

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative

This has been bothering me for some time, so I thought I'd finally ask it here. If we are given a function, say, $$f(x,y)=x^2+y^2,$$ and are asked to differentiate it w.r.t. $x$, i.e. $$\frac{\partial}{\partial x} f(x,y),$$ then surely this is the same as saying $$\frac{d}{dx} f(x,y),$$ since we will know by the context that obviously $$\frac{d}{dx} y^2 = 0,$$ and therefore $$\frac{\partial}{\partial x} f(x,y)=\frac{d}{dx} f(x,y)=2x.$$ Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are indeed missing something:
$\frac{d}{dx}y^2 \ne0$
since $\frac{d}{dx}y^2 = 2y \frac{dy}{dx}$

Note: $\frac{d}{dx} = \frac{d}{dy} \frac{dy}{dx}$

$$\frac{d}{dx}y^2 = \frac{d}{dy} (y^2) \frac{dy}{dx}$$
$$=2y \frac{dy}{dx}$$

This is often referred to as implicit differentiation, and can prove helpful in finding $\frac{dy}{dx}$ in certain cases where direct differentiation is more difficult, eg: $x^2 - xy + y^3 = 8$.

---

$$x^2 - xy + y^3 = 8$$
$$\frac{d}{dx}(x^2) - \frac{d}{dx}(xy) + \frac{d}{dx}(y^3) = \frac{d}{dx}(8)$$
$$2x -x \cdot \frac{dy}{dx} - y + 3y^2 \cdot \frac{dy}{dx} = 0$$ Where we have used:  $$u=-x,v=y$$$$u'=-1,v'=\frac{dy}{dx}$$
$$\frac{dy}{dx}(3y^2 - x) = -2x + y$$
$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{y -2x}{3y^2 - x}$$
by implicit differentiation.

Whereas by partial differentiation with respect to x, we would have obtained:

$$2x - y = 0$$

Which as you can see happens to be the top value of our implicit differential multiplied by $(-1)$, this is because implicit differentiation can be thought of as $-\frac{f_x}{f_y}$, being the partial derivative with respect to x divided by the partial with respect to y multiplied by $(-1)$.

Comment: Here $y$ is independent of $x$, unlike the example you posted of implicit differentiation.

Comment: Okay, now I'm a little confused. When Display Name said that $(d/dx) y^2 = 2y (dy/dx)$, would this only be the case if $y = y(x)$?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. This only occurs when $y$ varies with $x$. When we partial differentiate with respect to $x$, we hold $y$ constant. For example, the function $g(x,y) = y^3$ has zero partial derivative in the $x$ direction.

Comment: It depends what $f(x,y)$ is equal to. Here: $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = 2x$, $\frac{df}{dx} = 2x + 2y \cdot \frac{dy}{dx}$

Comment: $f(x,y)$ is a function on $\mathbb{R}^2$, defined by $f(x,y) = x^2 + y^2$. Can you give an example of a function on $\mathbb{R}^2$ for which $df/dx$ is not equal to $\partial f/\partial x$?

Comment: @Display Name, I would have thought that if our function is defined as $f(x,y) = x^2 + y^2$ then $y \neq y(x)$ and therefore $(d/dx) y^2 = 0$.

Comment: @user7388 If your question is "Is partially deriving with only two variables $x$ and $y$ with respect to $x$ equivalent to the partial derivative of the two variables $x$ and $y$ with respect to x?" In this case, **You are not partially deriving.**

Comment: @DisplayName my question is this: If we are given a function in two variables, for example $f(x,y) = x^2 + y^2$, where $x$ and $y$ are the independent variables (hence $y \neq y(x)$) and $f$ is the dependent variable, then would finding $(d/dx)f(x,y)$ be the same as $(\partial /\partial x)f(x,y)$? As an aside, as far as I know there is no such thing as "partially deriving".

Comment: @user7388 If $f(x,y) = z$, then you can partially derive it, and this will not be equal to taking a standard derivative where $y \ne y(x)$. As you can see $\frac{d}{dx} \equiv \frac{d}{dy} \cdot \frac{dy}{dx}$, hence the $\frac{dy}{dx}$ is left over after you  *only* consider the $\frac{d}{dy}$ and whatever $y$ term you have.

Comment: Ahh, okay, so $d/dx = (d/dy)(dy/dx)$ by definition; makes sense now, thanks @DisplayName.

Comment: @user7388 No problem at all!